# Android Web Font Only half rendered

Tags: android, mobile, web, svg, fonts

I have a website which is using web fonts for icons and shapes.
I have an issue on Android Browsers (mainly chrome and Amazon silk).

On everything the icon renders properly, but on the android browsers it only renders part of the Icon.
I have seen this work properly if I enable the svg file first, but the file is larger and I want a smallest size possible.

Does anyone know what causes this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "enable the svg file"?  Can you post the file, or html, or put it in a jsfiddle so we can test?  In this case, a screenshot is not that helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, the demo file is here: http://i-skool.co.uk/font_test/demo.html